# Creating dynamic button ID and sending the ID to a javascript function. Javascript function is not accepting

Tags: javascript, php, html

Trying to add dynamic id for button as

```
  echo "<input type='button' id='$butid' class='btn btn-info' data-target='#prodetails' onclick='show($butid)' value='Details'>";
```

in javascript function ive written

```
   <script>
           function show(x)
           {

               document.getElementById("prodetails").innerHTML=x;
           }
   </script>
```

Not able to recieve the value passed in the function call.
Value passed is varchar getting output as [object HTMLInputElement]

Comment: You've not wrapped the string value in quotes in the onclick assignment.

Comment: Your php variable doesnt get recognized as it is in the string. In your case you have to give the function you have written the value `$butid`. But your whole code doesnt make sense. Why to get the id of an item when you have to call it with the id? Please provide more code / info!

Comment: when i try to print the recieved value it says [object HTMLInputElement]

Comment: Quot the argument in the call. `onclick=\"show('$butid');\"`. Only numbers can be sent unquoted. Or even better `onclick='show(this);'` and use the element properties in your function.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev tried with onclick='show(this);' but when i print it shows [object HTMLInputElement]

Comment: Look at your generated **HTML** code. And show it in your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type='button' id=<?= $yourId ?> class='btn btn-info' data-target=<?= $dataYouWantToSend ?> onclick=show(this) value='Details'>


<script>
           function show(x)
           {

               x.innerHTML=x.data-target;  //data-target is equal to the data you want to send to function this will add innerHTML = your dynamic data 
               console.log(x.id); //here you will get your dynamic id

           }
   </script>
```

Modify your code as shown above , and It will work for sure , see you can not write html code in php "echo" , instead you should go for  where you want php code in HTML

Second thing suppose you want to send data to function then assign your data to the new attribute like you have written data-target

and pass the function "This" , this means the current element , in your case its button

Then access your data and id by " . " operator for e.g. x.id

I hope it will help you :)

Remember : `<?php echo "HII" ; ?>` can be written as `<?= "Hii" ?>`

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to get Id of element, based on what I guess about what you want to do you have to surround it with quotation marks (fix this part): `onclick='"show($butid)"'` .